# Why doesn't the reader process start?

Tags: python, process

I am learning to use Queue to communicate between two processes. Below is the snippet:

```
import os
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

def write(q):
    print("Begin to write data into queue in process:",os.getpid())
    for char in ['A','B','C']:
        print("Put %s to queue" %char)
        q.put(char)
        time.sleep(random.random())


def read(q):
    print("Begin to read data into queue in process: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    while True:
        value = q.get(True)
        print("Get {0} from queue".format(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q=Queue()
    #写队列进程
    process_writer=Process(target=write,args=(q,))
    #读队列进程
    process_reader=Process(target=read,args=(q,))
    process_writer.start()
    process_reader.start()
    #process_writer.join()  
    process_reader.terminate()
```

Hi, why doesn't the `process_reader` start evertime I comment the line `process_writer.join()`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't start? You're killing it just after starting.

Comment: Uncomment `process_writer.join()` and add one for the reader. This will make the parent wait for the children to exit. Then you need a way to get them to stop. One option is to have write put a `None` when its done and have the reader check for that value.

Comment: @CristiFati Hi, Why did it be killed?

Comment: `start()` the `terminate()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.